# run Node on other Master

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i have my robot developped on raspberry pi3 and it publish odometry and laserscan data.
i want to visualise this data on RVIZ install it on my PC.

What can i do please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236147/run-node-on-other-master/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just have to set your Environment Variables correctly in your case the `ROS_MASTER_URI` where you specify where your PC can find the Master documented [here.](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)

So you just have to open a new Terminal Window and enter `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://mia:11311/` (mia: my ip address). In your case enter the ip address of the raspberrypi instead of mia.

Than starting RVIZ with `rosrun rviz rviz`. (you also can check with `rostopic list` if your topics are available now).

--- Update --

Corresponding to your comment you have also set your ROS_IP. Sorry i forgot to tell you that.
So just find out your IP-Address with

```
hostname -I
```

and export it with

```
export ROS_IP=192.168.xxx.xxx
```

So you have to do both. Setup the ROS_MASTER_URI and the ROS_IP.
Please don’t forget to set the ROS_IP at your PC and the RaspberryPi.

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-06-07**:
thanks,
when i run rostopic list on my PC, i receive all topics but when i run rostopic bw /topic, i receive any data.
what can i do please?

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-06-07**:
i receive: Using transport "raw"
Couldn't find an AF_INET address